# Android app to quickly download an icon

Tags: android, icon

Every once in a while the icon associated with an Android app is so poorly designed that I want to change it.

My launcher allows me to select any icon for an app, so my process is:

1. Use a web browser to search for an icon that is suitable
2. Download the icon
3. Assign the icon to the app

Not the end of the world, but a bit cumbersome. The advantage of this process is that no extra bulky items (such as icon packs or themes) are installed, constantly using device storage.

Is there an app that lets you quickly search for icons and just download individual ones as needed?

I originally posted this on the Android StackExchange site, but was kindly requested to move it over here.

Comment: Which launcher is this...? (just so I could use it :)

Comment: @ṧнʊß Lightning Launcher eXtreme (LLX).  There is a free version called Lightning Launcher and an inexpensive paid version called Lightning Launcher eXtreme.  Highly recommended.

Comment: Yikes. Yes, that's the most customizable Launcher I've ever tried. Almost nothing you cannot customize (absolutely insane if you see some demo movies at Youtube!). I wonder it hasn't the required feature already built-in; have you asked the dev for it? Wouldn't be surprised seeing the idea picked-up, so you wouldn't need an extra app for that.